# Can I connect to local IP in office from home using remote desktop connection feature?

Tags: networking, ip, remote-desktop

Let's assume

in my company, I have a laptop that is currently connecting to a local db.

The connection is using an internal IP.

However, now I am at my house, I am unable to connect to the db because I am not in my office. But I have setup remote desktop connection communicating my laptop at home with the laptop in the office.

Can I know whether I can open a tomcat web apps and use the db connection?

I think the answer is no but I would like to know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have setup remote desktop connection communicating my laptop at home with the laptop in the office.
>
> Can I know whether I can open a tomcat web apps and use the db connection?

For accessing your office laptop via remote-desktop service, you must use a VPN connection from home laptop to your office network. Once onto the VPN pipe, its as good as you being present in your office premisis.Which means that you should be able to use your laptop to connect to systems is office (db , for example). You need not go via remote-desktop.

Answer (score 1):

I think these are two distinct subjects: Remote Desktop and something like VPN. The Remote Desktop is a service that gives you access to your desktop computer. The virtual private network (VPN) gives you access to a network.

A possible solution could be the following:
You provide a VPN-server in your office where your PC provides the remote desktop service. Then you can connect from the outside via VPN to the office-network and then access your PC via the remote desktop.